# Navigate Relationship soql

Tags: soql, relationships

My objects are:

```
CONTACT(lookup)-----ACCOUNT (master)-----ACCOUNT PLAN(detail/master)------INFLUENCER(detail)
```

I want create a lookup on `INFLUENCER` that shows only the contacts related.

With soql from the object `INFLUECER` how can i get the account and after the contact related?

Answer (score 2):

This would give all the Contacts whose Accounrs have Plans that have Influencers. You can add a where clause to the sub query to restrict the Influencers being selected

```
Select id, name from contact where AccountId     IN (select AccountPlan__r.Account__c from Influencer__c)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have this now :Select Account.id,id,name from contact where Account.id IN (SELECT Account_Plan__r.Account__c FROM Influencer__c) but i get an error : The inner select field 'Account_Plan__r.Account__c' cannot have more than one level of relationships